# How to create web deployment alone package using TFS

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I just need to create Web Deployement package using TFS build and don't want to deploy it automatically in IIS.

I have added the below two parameters in Build Definition - > MSBuild Arguments

> /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true

The probelm is I am not getting the ZIP file in drop location and getting the below error.

> C:\Program
> Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
> (1657): The "MapUriToIisWebServer" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): Unknown
> error (0x80005000)    at
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()    at
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer()    at
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.CheckIsContainer()    at
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.Find(String name, String
> schemaClassName)    at
> Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.MapUriToIisWebServer.get_IisMajorVersion()
> at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.MapUriToIisWebServer.Execute()    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost
> taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost
> taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask,
> Boolean& taskResult)

What could be the issue?

---

Now I am getting different error

> error : Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'manifest' and path 'e:\TFS\Dev\ApplicationName\Binaries\Release_PublishedWebsites\ApplicationName_Package\ApplicationName.SourceManifest.xml' cannot be created.)
>
> error : Object of type 'manifest' and path 'e:\TFS\Dev\ApplicationName\Binaries\Release_PublishedWebsites\ApplicationName_Package\ApplicationName.SourceManifest.xml' cannot be created.
>
> error : One or more entries in the manifest 'sitemanifest' are not valid.
>
> error : Application '/ApplicationName' does not exist in site 'Default Web Site'.

Comment: Those properties cause the web publishing pipeline to use your project settings unless you override them. Could you let us know how your publishing-related settings are configured in your project's properties?

Comment: "Create deployement package as a ZIP file" is checked

Comment: Tomas Scot has a blog post that describes the same issue here:
http://tomasscott.wordpress.com/tag/mapuritoiiswebserver/

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I've had nothing but success, simply by adding `/p:DeployOnBuild=true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you just need to add the 'Package' target to your build for the web project.

```
 /t:Build;Package
```

I've been using that target in my tfs build to generate the _PublishedWebsite folder with the package zip for a while now with success.

EDIT: Explanation of Package target
If you look at your csproj file for your web application as an XML file, you'll see that it includes the following

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

This includes a bunch of web targets into your build process.  Crack this file open and at the bottom you'll see that it in turn includes

```
 <Import Project="..\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" Condition="Exists('..\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets')" />
```

This file contains the definition of the Web Deployment process for MSBuild.  You'll see that it declares a variable to denote the "target" to invoke on a Deploy as being "Package"

```
 <DeployDefaultTarget Condition="'$(DeployDefaultTarget)'==''">Package</DeployDefaultTarget>
```

If you read through this file further it will give you an idea of how Packaging and Deployment work under the covers and what the set of properties and targets are you can manipulate to customize your build.

Long story short though, if you call

```
 msbuild yourwebapplication.csproj /t:Package /p:Configuration=Release
```

It should build you the web deployment package for the Release configuration of your app.

Comment: Can you explain about this more?

Comment: so `/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true` is not enough, we need to invoke the package target itself?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only thing that resolved it was this:

1. Open your IIS Management console
2. Go to your Default Web Site
3. Add new Application named 'ApplicationName'
4. Run msbuild again. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [MSBuild DeployOnBuild=true not publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962705/msbuild-deployonbuild-true-not-publishing)

I had the same problem with Atlassian Bamboo, and this fixed it for me: From a machine with Visual Studio copy the contents of "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web" to the TFS Build server.