# Building deployment package with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

We were building a **Visual Studio 2010** solution with the following **msbuild** command:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package
```

This command built the solution and created the deployment packages for web projects in the solution.

But after we've migrated to **Visual Studio 2012** this command doesn't work anymore. The solution is built, but no deployment packages are created.

How to fix it?

Comment: can you let me know - if a solution contains non web projects as well, will those be a part of the package that is generated by the msbuild? I am new to the .NET world, and i trying to get the concept of "build once and deploy anywhere". If the non web projects are left out than, my theory to build a single package for the solution is not going to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was exactly the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962705/msbuild-deployonbuild-true-not-publishing).
Copying *C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web** from a local machine to a remote CI server.

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem?

Answer (score -1):

I use this manually, should be a matching msbuild parameter

[Using the Publish Web Wizard to Create a Deployment Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323.aspx)

Comment: What parameter do you mean? Manual publishing is not a case. It's on a CI server.