# One of my two TFS servers is missing VisualStudio tools in msbuild folder. Need help locating the package required to install them

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msdeploy

I have two servers, ServerA and ServerB. Both servers have these installed:

- Web Deploy 3.5" installed via Web Platform Installer
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK
- TFS 2013

ServerA is missing files that ServerB has. This is a huge problem because my MSBuild build arguments "/p:DeployOnBuild=True" do not work on ServerA unless I copy these specific files over.

**ServerA**
[image: ServerA]
**ServerB**
[image: ServerB]

When I manually copy these files over everything is fixed. But this isnt good practice and I need solid documentation on how to configure these servers. This post is what helped me find the issue: [MSBuild DeployOnBuild=true not publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962705/msbuild-deployonbuild-true-not-publishing/9407607#9407607)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always advise installing visual studio on the build servers.  That should fix your problems.

Comment: Thank you. Also do licenses matter? Should I do express? I assume an expired license wouldn't matter as all the tools would still be there.

Comment: Microsoft explicitly allows you to install VS on your build server without having to purchase additional licenses - so long as somebody in your team/company has a valid VS license.  Not only that you can install the highest edition for which you have a license.  So for example, if your team has 12 VS Pro licenses and 1 VS Ultimate, you can install VS Ultimate on every build server free of charge.

Comment: Can you link any offical documentation on this statement regarding 'free' build license ?